# Broken links in only single HTML div tag; other links work

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

Why am I getting broken links in just a single section of my website, hosted on Github pages? The webiste is lanl.github.io/LaGriT . The relevant part of the HTML layout file looks like this:

```
<div id="top_right">
   <a href="https://lanl.github.io/LaGriT/"> Home </a> <br>
    <div class="grid" id="searchBar">
          <div>
              <div id="search">
                  <form role="search" method="get" action="{{ site.baseurl }}//pages/search">
                      <input id="searchString" name="searchString"
                             placeholder="Enter text here" type="text">
                      <input id="searchButton" name="googleSearchName" type="button" value="Search">
                  </form>
              </div>

          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The corresponding part of the CSS file looks like this:

```
#top_right {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px; right:200px;
    width:400px;
    background:#000;
}
```

Comment: Links work fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: @disinfor The links at the top right are not working for me on any browser. (the manual, home, site map, and site index links). Can you confirm these work for you?

Comment: Yes, they work for me.

Comment: Your HTML looks broken. All of the <meta> tags are in the <body>. You are probably missing a closing tag somewhere. The header is positioned over the top of the links.

Comment: @Turnip No it's not broken. This is just part of the HTML code.

Comment: <meta> tags are only allowed within the <head> tag so yes, your HTML is broken.

Comment: OK. I guess I define "broken" differently because the website was still rendering.

Comment: Ok, your HTML is _invalid_ because meta tags must be in the head, not the body.  When html is invalid the browser will try to guess what it should be, and may add or remove (closing) tags. e.g. a ul is not allowed within a p so given this, which is invalid: `<p>text <ul><li>thing</li></ul></p>` the browser will change/interpret is as this: `<p>text</p> <ul><li>thing</li></ul>` While these often display correctly it makes your CSS and your Javascript unpredictable, because you don't know what the DOM tree _really_ looks like, and different browsers can make different changes. You should fix it.

Comment: @StephenP Noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your browser's developer tools and inspect some elements, you will see that the `<div id="header_wrap">` overlays (is on top of) the `<div id="top_right">`.

DOM elements are stacked based on the order they appear in the page source; later elements are put on top of earlier elements.

The easiest way to fix that is to set a higher `z-index` on top_right.

```
#top_right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 100;     /*  <-----  */
}
```

You could also change the order of the elements declaration, for example put your top_right div at the *end* of the HTML source so it is on the top of the z-index stack. Since you're using `position: absolute` it shouldn't matter where it appears in the source, but it *will* change the tab order, so that may not be desireable.